# What can I do to make this code work? (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the assignment:

> SUMMER OF '69: Return the sum of the numbers in the array, except ignore sections of numbers starting with a 6 and' \
>   extending to the next 9 (every 6 will be followed by at least one 9). Return 0 for no numbers.

This is my code:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    a = len(arr)
    sum = 0

    for i in range(0,a):

      if arr[i]!=6:
        sum+=arr[i]
        continue

      if (arr[i]==6):
          for i in range(i+1,a):
              if i==9:
                  sum+=0
                  i+=1
                  break

    return sum
```

When my input is:

```
d = summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print(d)
```

the output is 33 instead of 9.

What's the problem?
I saw a different way to solve this one in the course solution but I want to know what's wrong specifically in this code.

Comment: `i+=1` in the inner loop **does not** change the next value of `i` you'll get from `range`in the outer loop.

Comment: Got you.. still not working, help? :)
def summer_69(arr):
    a = len(arr)
    sum = 0

    for i in range(0,a):
      if arr[i]!=6:
        sum+=arr[i]

      if (arr[i]==6):
          for i in range(i+1,a):
              if i==9:
                  break

    return sum

Comment: I'd suggest some actual debugging, maybe add some prints in at the very least.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actually easier with generators.

```
def gen_summer_69(arr):
    arr_i = iter(arr)
    while 1:
        n = next(arr_i)
        if n == 6:
            while next(arr_i) != 9:
                pass
        else:
            yield n
```

This filters the results according to the criteria you mentioned, so you can just sum the result.

```
sum(gen_summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]))
```

So, as a function it would be:

```
def summer_69(arr):
    return sum(gen_summer_69(arr))
```

Which could be called like you desire:

```
summer_69([4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

Edit: I will refrain from using generators since you asked nicely.

```
def summer_69(arr):
    arr_len = len(arr)
    arr_sum = 0
    skip = False
    for i in range(arr_len):
        n = arr[i]
        if skip:
            if n == 9:
                skip = False
            continue
        if n == 6:
            skip = True
        else:
            arr_sum += n
    return arr_sum
```

Comment: The truth is that I'm learning from a Udemy course and we didn't learn generators yet.. can you try to fix my way of solution?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you reassign `i` (e.g. using an inner loop), the outer loop still will get the next value from `range`, so the assignment will have no effect (e.g. on your outer loop).
You could remove the inner loop, and just set a flag, which lets you know whether you should use or skip the current number.

Comment: Ok thank you for helping.. I guess that with my current knowledge I cant solve this task with my way anyway.. (I didn't learn flags or generators)

Comment: By 'flag' i am just referring to a boolean variable.